# checking count of model list items in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working with MVC 4 and using this model:

```
public class Cat {        

    public string Name { get; set; }         
    public IEnumerable<Cat> Children {...}

}
```

My view contains the corresponding `Children` list.  I have a check in the Razor to see if `Children` is null:

```
  @if (category.Children!=null)
  { 
     <span class="right-plus main-plus"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></span>
  }
```

I also check to see how many `Children` there are:

```
  @if (category.Children.Count()>0)
  { 
     <span class="right-plus main-plus"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></span>
  }
```

But if count is 0 then both span classes are shown.  How can I only show one of the above spans if there are zero `Children`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:-

```
@if(Model.Children != null){
   if(Model.Children.Count > 0){
     <span class="right-plus main-plus"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></span>
   }
}
```

Comment: it shows error 'Non-invocable member 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...direct.data.cat>
    .Count' cannot be used like a method.' in the part if(Model.Children.Count() > 0)

Comment: @shyama...ohhh..sorry ... my fault..there will be no `()` in `.Count`..updated the answer now try it.

Comment: it shows me the error "RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count'" I am using .netcoreapp2.2 as my TragetFramework any ideas?